# How do I create a half transparent image with empty middle

Tags: image-processing, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to create a half transparent image with a empty rectangle at the middle like below:
[image]

How do I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and more flexible way (it will allow you to use percentage or fix position and size) might just be to use 4 rectangle like this:

```
 <Grid Opacity="0.5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

or you could use a Path Geometry:

```
 <Path  StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Black" Opacity=".5" >
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,100,100" />
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,300,200"  />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```